# Brezis 4.15, $f_n(x)=ne^{−nx}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere

Let $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $f_n(x)=ne^{-nx}$ prove that

(i) $f_n\rightarrow0$ a.e.
(ii) $f_n$ is bounded in $L_1(\Omega)$

I know that for $f_n$ to converge a.e. to zero, the set of points in which this does not happen must have zero measure i think it has something to do with the interval $\left[0,\dfrac{1}{2n}\right]$ but I have no idea how to proceed. I don't know what to do with (ii)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there a sign missing in the exponential? $-nx$?

Comment: Yes thanks, edited now

Comment: Re (1), show that $f_n(x)\to0$ for **every** $x$ in $(0,1)$. Re (ii), compute every $\|f_n\|_1$.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful for 1 (had to use L'Hopital), still working on 2.

Comment: both helpful thanks